# Substring from char in C

Tags: c

I have a `char[1000]` and I have the position of `|` which is the char that I wanna use to split...
For example I have `user|pass` I have the position of `|`. Now I wanna get substring from 0 to `|` and `|` to end

Here is my code..

```
void fileManager () {
    char c[1000];
    char username[1000];
    char senha[1000];
    FILE *fptr;
    if ((fptr=fopen("file.txt","r"))==NULL){
        printf("Error! opening file");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (fscanf(fptr, "%s", c) !=EOF) {
        int posicaoSubstring = -1;
        posicaoSubstring = procurarSubstring(c, "|");
        if(posicaoSubstring == -1)
            printf("\n | not found \n");
        else {
            printf("\n position of | %d\n", posicaoSubstring+1);
            username = // 0 to | from c
            senha = // | to end C
        }
        printf("%s\n", c);
    }
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

Comment: `strtok(string, "|")`?

Comment: it works for get username...and from | to end? :D

Comment: `sscanf(c, "%[^|]|%s", username, senha);`

Comment: The return value of `char *strtok(char *, char *)` is the pointer to pass, in your case.